# Matlab - Subtract 1 vector with another in struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have to different struct arrays(In the same Matlab file), what I want is to take 1 parameter/vector from a variable in a struct array and subtract it with different parameters from another variable in another struct array, is this possible?

Here is a small part of my code:

```
Dist(1).name = 'Pristina'
Dist(1).KM_To_Fushe_ks = 13.7   % 199-13.7 = 
Dist(1).KM_to_Lipjan = 8.7      % 199-8.7  =
Dist(1).KM_to_Sllatina = 4.2    % 199-4.2  =
Dist(1).KM_to_Hajvali = 3.5     % 199-3.5  =
Dist(1).KM_to_Mitrovica = 46.9  % 199-46.9 = 
Dist(1).KM_to_Anija = 1.9       % 199-1.9  =



EV(1).name = 'Nissan Leaf 24 kWh pack'
EV(1).RangeInKM_By_Manufacturer = 199 %SUBTRACT this with parameters above:
EV(1).Battery_Capacity = 21.6
EV(1).Battery_Warranty_KM = 100000
EV(1).Battery_Warrany_Year = 5
EV(1).EnginePower_Kw = 80
EV(1).EnginePower_hK = 109
EV(1).Torque_in_NewtonMeter = 254
EV(1).QuickCharging_type = 'CHAdeMO'
EV(1).QuickChargingEffect_kW_DC = 50
EV(1).NormalCharging_OnBoard_kW_AC = 3.3
EV(1).Seats = 5
EV(1).Luggage_in_Liters = 370
EV(1).Consumption_Mixed_kWh_per_10km_NEDC = 1.5
EV(1).Weight_Without_Driver = 1475
EV(1).TopSpeed_KM_per_hour = 144
EV(1).Acceleration_0to100KM_per_hour = 11.5
EV(1).RangeInKM_By_Manufacturer_RANK = 10
```

What I want is to have the number off 199 as a vector, and substract it by all these numbers `= [13.7, 8.7, 4.2, 3.5, 46.9, 1.9]`

How to do this?

Comment: Ok, so It was that simple in that way i just had to create a new variable:

Remaining_Range_in_KM = EV(1).RangeInKM_By_Manufacturer - Dist(1).KM_To_Fushe_ks 

And then it creates a new array called "Remaining_Range_in_KM", so now I just need to figure out how I can get all distances.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misinterpret your question, but this seem to work:

```
EV(1).RangeInKM_By_Manufacturer = 199 - Dist(1).KM_To_Fushe_ks
```

In the line you quote in your question, you left the initialization of `KM_To_Fushe_ks` after the difference; in short, you cannot have to vaiable assignements in the same command.
Also, if you end your lines with semi-colons you will suppress the output to the command window. Like this:

```
Dist(1).name = 'Pristina';
Dist(1).KM_To_Fushe_ks = 13.7;   
Dist(1).KM_to_Lipjan = 8.7;    
% Etc...
```

Comment: This is what I did yesterday(Answered it on my own comment).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to my problem:

```
distances = [KM_to_Fushe_KS, KM_to_Lipjan];


remainingrange = arrayfun(@(s) s.RangeInKM - distances, EV, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Or I could do this:

```
remainingrange = cell(size(EV));
for evidx = 1:numel(EV)
    remaingrange{evidx} = EV(evidx).RangeInKM - distances;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is doing is putting multiple distances in once matrix:

Example:

```
Towns = {'Town1', 'Town2', 'Town3', 'Town4'};
distances = [0 200 13.7 8.7;
             200 0 13.3 9.3;
             13.7 13.3 0 255;
             8.7 9.3 255 0];


EVs = {'Nissan Leaf 24 kWh pack', 'Nissan Leaf 30 kWh pack'};
ranges = [199 250];
```

And then I can calculate distances as a 3D matrix:

```
remainingrange = permute(ranges, [1 3 2]) - distances;  
remainingrange = bsxfun(@minus, permute(ranges, [1 3 2]), distances);
```

If I want to check if a EV has not enough range in KM, I could write:

```
 tooFarForMyEV = find(remainingrange < 0)
 [from, to, ev] = ind2sub(size(remainingrange), tooFarForMyEV);
 lackingrange = table(Towns(from)', Towns(to)', EVs(ev)', remainingrange(tooFarForMyEV), 'VariableNames', {'From', 'To', 'EV', 'Deficit'})
```